# how to set the value at particular position in expandableListView

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

i have created a ExpandableListView.But There is a problem when i set the value of particular item same value set on all item i can not understand how to solve this.

this is my code.

direct_referal.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutfaq"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is My Main Xml File.

DirectReferal.java

```
public class DirectReferalFragment extends Fragment 
{

    ExpandableDirectReferalListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    private List<String> userID;
    private List<String> joiningDate;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> slNo;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> name;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> city;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.direct_referal, container, false);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        expListView.setGroupIndicator(null);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableDirectReferalListAdapter(this.getActivity(), userID, joiningDate, slNo, name, city);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {

                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        userID = new ArrayList<String>();
        joiningDate = new ArrayList<String>();
        slNo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        name = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        city = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding USER ID
        userID.add("User ID : GLI000014");
        userID.add("User ID : GLI000015");
        userID.add("User ID : GLI000016");
        userID.add("User ID : GLI000017");
        userID.add("User ID : GLI000018");

        // Adding JOINING DATE
        joiningDate.add("Joining Date : 9 Nov,2015");
        joiningDate.add("Joining Date : 9 Dec,2015");
        joiningDate.add("Joining Date : 9 Jan,2016");
        joiningDate.add("Joining Date : 9 Fab,2016");
        joiningDate.add("Joining Date : 9 Mar,2016");

        // Adding SL NO
        List<String> no1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        no1.add("SL No. : 1");
        List<String> no2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        no2.add("SL No. : 2");
        List<String> no3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        no3.add("SL No. : 3");
        List<String> no4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        no4.add("SL No. : 4");
        List<String> no5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        no5.add("SL No. : 5");

        slNo.put(userID.get(0), no1); // Header, Child data
        slNo.put(userID.get(1), no2);
        slNo.put(userID.get(2), no3);
        slNo.put(userID.get(3), no4);
        slNo.put(userID.get(4), no5);

        // Adding NAME
        List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        name1.add("Name : Prabal Saxena");
        List<String> name2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        name2.add("Name : Chirag Mehta");
        List<String> name3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        name3.add("Name : Tarun Mehta");
        List<String> name4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        name4.add("Name : Prashant Gupta");
        List<String> name5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        name5.add("Name : Chotu");

        name.put(userID.get(0), name1); // Header, Child data
        name.put(userID.get(1), name2);
        name.put(userID.get(2), name3);
        name.put(userID.get(3), name4);
        name.put(userID.get(4), name5);

        // Adding CITY
        List<String> city1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        city1.add("City : Noida");
        List<String> city2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        city2.add("City : Gurgaun");
        List<String> city3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        city3.add("City : Delhi");
        List<String> city4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        city4.add("City : Pune");
        List<String> city5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        city5.add("SL No. : Delhi");

        city.put(userID.get(0), city1); // Header, Child data
        city.put(userID.get(1), city2);
        city.put(userID.get(2), city3);
        city.put(userID.get(3), city4);
        city.put(userID.get(4), city5);
    }
}
```

This is my main Java file. in this we set the value of all child and parent element and send the value via constructor.

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/direct_referal_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItemslno"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItemname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItemcity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_group.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="#333333">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeaderuserid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="User ID : GLI000014"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeaderjoindate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Joining Date : 9 Nov, 2015"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ExpandableDirectReferalListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableDirectReferalListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;

    List<String> _userID;
    List<String> _joiningDate;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> _slNo;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> _name;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> _city;

    public ExpandableDirectReferalListAdapter(Context context, List<String> userID,List<String> joiningDate,
                                              HashMap<String, List<String>> slNo,HashMap<String, List<String>> name,
                                              HashMap<String, List<String>> city) {
        this._context = context;
        this._userID = userID;
        this._joiningDate = joiningDate;
        this._slNo = slNo;
        this._name = name;
        this._city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._slNo.get(this._userID.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChildslno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemslno);
        TextView txtListChildname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemname);
        TextView txtListChildcity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemcity);

        txtListChildslno.setText(childText);
        txtListChildname.setText(childText);
        txtListChildcity.setText(childText);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._slNo.get(this._userID.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._userID.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._userID.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater=(LayoutInflater)this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeaderuserid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderuserid);
        TextView lblListHeaderjoindate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderjoindate);

        lblListHeaderuserid.setText(headerTitle);
        lblListHeaderjoindate.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my Adapter class.in this we want to set diffrent value of all child and parent field but same value set on all field.
you can see the the output in this image..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prgi9.png)

How can i solve this problem, I can not understant.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct getChildView method gand etGroupView method. The code will be as follows.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String slNo = _slNo.get(_userID.get(groupPosition)).get(0);
        String childName = _name.get(_userID.get(groupPosition)).get(0);
        String childCity = _city.get(_userID.get(groupPosition)).get(0);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChildslno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemslno);
        TextView txtListChildname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemname);
        TextView txtListChildcity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemcity);

        txtListChildslno.setText(slNo);
        txtListChildname.setText(childName);
        txtListChildcity.setText(childCity);

        return convertView;
    }




@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater=(LayoutInflater)this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeaderuserid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderuserid);
    TextView lblListHeaderjoindate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderjoindate);

    lblListHeaderuserid.setText(headerTitle);
    lblListHeaderjoindate.setText(_joiningDate.get(groupPosition));

    return convertView;
}
```

Hope that you can understand what was your mistake..
I tested the code, it will work.

Comment: please consider to accept my answer as I took some time for you..:)